# How to automatically expand a a4j:outputPanel?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

How can i expand an a4j:outputPanel, if the scrollbar enters a certain area? With the word expand i mean, that more of the data from my java bean will be shown in the a4j:outputPanel.

A small code example:

```
<h:panelGroup id="container">
   <a4j:repeat value="#{bean.someValues}" var="varForMyBean">
      <a4j:outputPanel>        
         <div>
            <h:outputText value="#{varForMyBean.value}"
         </div>
      </a4j:outputPanel>
   </a4j:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
```

The JSF panelGroup render a area in my gui, that will be make my data visible and creates a scrollbar.

But if the user enters a certain area with the scrollbar, this panelgroup must be expand without changing the layout position in the xhtml page.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with `a4j:outputPanel` here. `a4j:outputPanel` produces regular HTML `div` element without any styles. And by default `div` stretches horizontally and vertically as  it's content requires.

Check your custom CSS styles you have and styles of parent elements of `div/a4j:outputPanel` for something like `overflow: auto`. It's easier to do using Firebug or Development Tools in your browser.